# socket: Too many open files (24) Apache bench lighttpd

Tags: apache, scalability, lighttpd, file-descriptor

When I start Apache Bench test:

> ab -n 10000 -c 1300 `http://example.com/test.php`

I get error:

> socket: Too many open files (24)

When I change it to '-c 1000' it works fine.

Because I can have more than 1000 concurrent users I would like to fix socket too many open files problem or increase parameter. How to do this and where?

I use lighttpd on CentOS 5.

Comment: `When i change to '-c 1000' it works fine.` that helped to stay lazy ;)

Answer (score 98, accepted):

```
ulimit -n 10000
```

That might not work depending on you system configuration
Consult [this](http://www.cs.uwaterloo.ca/~brecht/servers/openfiles.html) to configure your system.

Comment: by default most systems limit number of file descriptors by 1024 per user. you need to jump through hoops to let you create more as described in the article I refer to. It worked on centos5 for me.

Comment: Worked fine with OS X EL Capitan too.

Comment: ^ DON'T do that ^

Comment: @jeffci why? Can you explain better?

Answer (score 3):

to permernent change max opened files limit, you should modify /etc/security/limits.conf and reboot system:

```
echo -ne " 
* soft nofile 65536 
* hard nofile 65536 
" >>/etc/security/limits.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [documentation](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Server.max-fdsDetails) for lighty. You might have to set the `server.max-fds` option. Also `server.max-connections` should be changed accordingly (again, see [the documentation](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Server.max-connectionsDetails)).